# Does this integral have a closed-form solution: $\int_b^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{1+x^2} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I'm very rusty with calculus, and I was hoping someone would be willing to help me with the following definite integral:

$$\int_b^{\infty}  \frac{\cos(ax)}{1+x^2} dx$$

$$b>0$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does it in Mathematica, but it ain't pretty: Integrate[Cos[a*x]/(1 + x^2), {x, b, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {b > 0, a > 0}] // FullSimplify

Comment: I'm thinking curiosity's going to win and I'm going to end up looking in a table of integrals to see if this is in there.

Comment: Thanks for trying everyone.

Answer (score 3):

For $b = 0$ or $b = -\infty$ you can use contour integration. For other $b$ (assuming $a \neq 0$), you will have to do it numerically.

(If there were a formula in terms of $b$, you would have an elementary formula for an antiderivative of the integrand (just differentiate your formula with respect to $b$ and you'll recover the negative of the integrand!), but there is no elementary formula for an antiderivative of this integrand, I believe).

Comment: There may not be an elementary antiderivative for this particular function (I haven't worked on it, so I can't say for sure), but it is still possible to have a closed form solution to this integral.

Comment: But you could differentiate any closed form solution to this integral with respect to b, so a closed form solution is the same as (the negative of) an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: I had a counterexample in mind when I made that comment.  If we evaluate $\int_0^b \sin(\frac{1}{x})\, dx$, we can differentiate the closed form solution (which is expressible in terms of the cosine integral) with respect to $b$, but that integrand does not necessarily admit an elementary antiderivative.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This will be a non elementary solution which leaves the chance for expanding closed form solutions in terms of special functions like the [trigonometric integral function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral). This uses the cosine [series representation](https://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/the-maclaurin-expansion-of-cosx/). Also see this [fun graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/24z2lkzfg9). [Integration proof](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5E%282n%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29+dx) and [formulas for integration](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/).

Sum representation:

$$\mathrm{\int \frac{cos(ax)}{x^2+1}dx=\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!} dx= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}}{(2n)!}\int \frac{x^{2n}}{x^2+1}dx= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}x^{2n+1} \,_2F_1\left(1,n+\frac12,n+\frac 32,-x^2\right)}{(2n+1)!}+C=C+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}x^{2n+1}\left(n+\frac12\right)Ф\left(-x^2,1,n+\frac12\right)}{(2n+1)!}}$$

The [hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/) can be decomposed into a [Lerch Transcendent function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

Closed form of your integral using [dlmf 6.7.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.7#E3), [complex cosine definition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cosine.html), and you could also use [partial fraction decomposition](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/partial-fractions.html) to derive formula 6.7.3 with the use of the [Exponential Integral function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) with b>0. The substitution is based on [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E+infinity+1%2F2+%28-i+cosh%28e%29+Ci%28-e+%28x+-+i%29%29+%2B+i+cosh%28e%29+Ci%28e+%28x+%2B+i%29%29+%2B+sinh%28e%29+%28Si%28i+e+-+e+x%29+-+Si%28e+%28x+%2B+i%29%29%29%29+):

$$\mathrm{\int_b^\infty \frac{cos(ax)}{x^2+1}dx=\frac12 \int_b^\infty \frac{e^{aix}}{x^2+1}dx+ \frac12 \int_b^\infty \frac{e^{-aix}}{x^2+1}dx= \frac{\pi}{2e^a}+\frac{1}{2}\big(i\, cosh(a)\, [Ci(a ( i-b)) - Ci(a (b + i)] + sinh(a)[Si(a (b + i)) +\, Si(a(i  -  b)]\big)=  \frac{\pi}{2e^a}+\frac14 i e^a [Ei(-a(i b + 1)  - 
 Ei(a(i b- 1))] - \frac14 i e^{-a}[ Ei(a(1 - i b)) + Ei(a(i b+ 1))]}$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!